# How to validate that bootstrap validation popup message is being displayed with Selenium and browser console?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

How do you locate a error message that appears as a tooltip in the browser console? It disappears before I can inspect it.
I was thinking the firstname field's error message would be this, but selenium cannot find it.

```
 static By firstnameerror = By.cssSelector
 ("div.row-fluid.first-name-container>div.errorMessageBox");     

 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait (webdriver, 60);
 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(createacct));
 WebElement create_acct = webdriver.findElement(createacct);
 create_acct.click();

 WebElement iframeSwitch = webdriver.findElement(
 By.id("register-  iframe"));
 webdriver.switchTo().frame(iframeSwitch);
 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(submit));
 WebElement submitbtn = webdriver.findElement(submit);
 submitbtn.click();

 String pleasefilloutthisfield = 
 webdriver.findElement(firstname).getText();
 log.info("FirstName error message: "+pleasefilloutthisfield);
```

[image]

Comment: You can try using a hybrid tool, such as TestComplete or Ranorex, they will help you locate it; having said it, even you can locate this tooltip with a hybrid tool, it does not mean you can find it using Selenium in a console.

Comment: Thanks. Are those free tools?

Comment: No, but you can download trial versions

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/webdriver/sUy6IKpQsHw).

You can't get the text, but the `required` attribute defaults to the standard text "please fill out this field", so you can check the `required` attribute.

```
 WebElement first_name = webdriver.findElement(firstname);

String pleasefilloutthisfield = first_name.getAttribute("required");

log.info("Got firstName error message: "+pleasefilloutthisfield);
```

Answer (score 0):

open the URL in Chrome and as soon as your Element appears (the one that disappear quickly ) click F8 , this will stop DOM from running and you can loca